Will "ten-week" stocks seedlings flower this summer?
I bought, at a plant sale, four little pots marked "stocks ten week dwarf mix"; each seedling is young with 4-6 leaves so far.
What does "ten week" refer to here; does it mean they will be flowering within ten weeks of planting, or something else? Should I be planting these out soon, or keeping them in pots and planting them out this Autumn for them to mature next year?

10 week perfume is a named variety of the stock (Matthiola incana) flower. It is listed as a hardy annual, so you should plant it out when past most expectation of frost. Related to cabbages...
No endorsement implied, just an example:

Image source.

I'll do that, cheers.
